# Is there any way to recover a file to the state it was in before the last save?

Tags: backup, html, visual-studio-code, recovery

Is there any way to recover a (html)file to the state it was in before the last save?

Wanting to see the result of a few lines of code, I deleted almost all my code and saved to see the new result. Unfortunately, I stumbled and the wire of my laptop was disconnected (and ihad to reboot my computer). So I can't use the undo button to go back to the previous version of my code.

I am left with 4 lines of code and I unfortunately lost everything else. I wanted to know if there is a way to go back to a previous state of my file? I tried with the windows system from the file properties but it does not offer me a previous version. I use Vscode.

Comment: For the future, you might like to learn about [Use Git version-control tools in Visual Studio Code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/use-git-from-vs-code/). Version control is a way of keeping previous versions of your files, and more.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possibilities that I can think of:

- Look in the Recycle Bin
- Look in the same folder.

You should be looking for a file with the same name, or with a mangled
version of the name (enable viewing hidden files).

If nothing is found, I fear that your file is lost.

Comment: Also, look in File History if that's enabled. (Although in this case the OP did check "Previous versions", which includes File History.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have these possibilities. I'll just redo it, thanks anyway.